# Is the fact true that GPT-3 wasn't trained on any explicitly gathered code dataset?

Tags: natural-language-processing

The [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.00027.pdf) mentions a line about GPT-3's training dataset -

`Motivated by the ability of GPT-3 (Brown et al., 2020) to generate plausible code completions despite its training data not containing any explicitly gathered code datasets`

My question - I need clarification on the following:

1. If it was not trained on any "explicitly gathered code datasets", did the actual dataset on which it was trained on, contained some amount of code or exactly no code?
2. If not, then how did it develop an ability to generate any code without learning what code really is?

Comment: My guess is that it used a lot of Wikipedia and internet text, some of which is code.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/165680/755, https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/43838/1794.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2):

Presumably "explicitly gathered" means that they didn't go out of their way to collect datasets specifically focused on code.

Undoubtedly the datasets they did use contained some code in it.  The GPT3 paper says it was trained on a filtered version of CommonCrawl.  This includes data from many sources that likely contain some code.  For instance, Wikipedia contains code.  So do some arXiv articles, some blog posts, some Stack Exchange answers, and many other sources.

Comment: 99% of the code that I write that ends up on the internet doesn’t work. (Because I try to tell people how to do it themselves; I’m not a code writing service). That’s probably the same for many developers. Good luck for any brainlessly text manipulation machine to create working code from this.